# insert function points to new data

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi i am frankly new to these forums so i tried looking up as much as i could but i couldn't find anything relate-able to my problem.

I am trying to read nodes that i stored into a file and insert them into a linked list that i created

THE insert functions works perfectly fine however while loading it when i attempt to insert the node ,
1.it inserts the node

2.reads the new node

3.since im using a pointer , the pointer now points to the new read node

4.inserts the newly read node from the file into the list overwriting the old data.

This causes my old data to be completely lost and the new node to act as the header of the file

load function :

```
    void load_file_students(linked_student &students)

    {
    node_student *test = new node_student;
    ifstream stu_list("students.dat",ios::binary);
    stu_list.read((char*)test, sizeof(*test));
    while (!stu_list.eof())
    {
        //students.insert_node_list(test);

        students.insert_node_list(test);
        stu_list.read((char*)test, sizeof(*test));

    }
    stu_list.close();


    }
```

the insert_node function:

```
        void linked_student::insert_node_list(node_student *student)
        {
        node_student* temp = new node_student;
        temp = student;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            node_student *ptr = this->head;
            while (ptr->next != 0)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            temp->previous = ptr;
            ptr->next= temp;

        }
        }
```

the node :

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
static int roll_number = 1; // used for the personal identification of the student 
class node_student
{
public:
    bool fees_paid = true;
    string name;
    float CGPA;
    int ID; // same as the static roll_number provided
    int semester;
    string department;
    string elective_subjects[5];
    node_student *next;
    node_student *previous;
    node_student();
    ~node_student();

   };
```

during debugging mode it is evident that when i re-read the data in the load function during

stu_list.read((char*)test, sizeof(*test));

it overwrites the old data in the insert function as well even though it is called before this line.

Once again the insertion into the file works perfectly fine , i can actually see the values being loaded via the debugging mode 
here is the insert function for reference

INSERT :

```
void update_student_file(linked_student testing)
{
    node_student *temp = testing.head;

    ofstream stu_list("students.dat",ios::binary);

    while (temp != NULL)
    {

        stu_list.write((char*)temp, sizeof(*temp));
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    stu_list.close();

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Btw this `node_student* temp = new node_student; temp = student;` is a memory leak

Comment: You can't save object with `std::string` members like that. (Well, you obviously *can*, but they are of no use when you read them afterwards as they will be invalid.) You need to read about serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here a fix to `load_file_students`:

```
void load_file_students(linked_student &students)
{
  node_student test; //way use dynamic allocation?
  ifstream stu_list("students.dat",ios::binary);
  while (stu_list.read((char*)test, sizeof(*test)))
  {
    students.insert_node_list(&test);
  }
  //file will be closed at the destructor.
}
```

### Another fix for `insert_node_list`

```
void linked_student::insert_node_list(node_student *student)
{
    node_student* temp = new node_student;
    *temp = *student; //call copy constructor, do not copy pointer value.
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node_student *ptr = this->head;
        while (ptr->next != 0)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        temp->previous = ptr;
        ptr->next= temp;
    }
}
```